# Multiplication of cross product with Levi-Civita symbol

Tags: cross-product

I want to show following property for the scalar product

$$
\left( \vec \omega \times \vec y,\vec \omega \times \vec y\right)=\left( \vec \omega,\vec y\times \left(\vec \omega \times \vec y\right)\right).
$$

I would like to show it by using the Levi-Civita symbol $\varepsilon_{ijk}$  since I am not practised with it. My first attempt is

$$
\left(\varepsilon_{ijk}\vec e_i \omega_j y_k\right)\cdot\left(\varepsilon_{ijk}\vec e_i \omega_j y_k\right)=\omega_j\varepsilon_{ijk}\vec e_i y_k\varepsilon_{ijk}\vec e_i \omega_j y_k
$$

but I do not see how I have to proceed. May you give me some adivce?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: First, use different indices: $(\epsilon_{ijk}e_i\omega_j y_k) \cdot (\epsilon_{lmn}e_l\omega_m y_n)$. Then [observe that](http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~ntg/834/notes/tensor_intro.pdf) $\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{imn} = \delta_{jm}\delta_{kn} - \delta_{jn}\delta_{km}$ and $e_i \cdot e_j = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: +1 for the hint and, most of all, for "use different indices".